# login command using c# and vs 2013

Tags: c#, .net, database, visual-studio

I want to execute a login stored procedure which is in my database but it always throws `InvalidOperationException` at `conn.open()`.

```
protected void signin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connStr = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newSchool"]);
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("login_proc", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    string username = txt_username.Value;
    string password = txt_password.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", username));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", password));


    // output parm
    SqlParameter count = cmd.Parameters.Add("@respond", SqlDbType.Int);
    count.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    if (count.Value.ToString().Equals("1"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://localhost:17009/Student_signup.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://localhost:17009/Welcome%20page.aspx");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your connection string is right?

Comment: Which error? Stack trace?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open%28v=vs.110%29.aspx . It seems that either your connectionstring is not correct or you already have your connection open.

Comment: The configured string is stored in a [`ConnectionString` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettings.connectionstring.aspx): `string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newSchool"].ConnectionString;`

Comment: i think the connection string is correct

Comment: @user3100088: Know or know not, there is no think. If somebody is suggesting something is wrong and your program is not working then you should actually check that. I presume that if everything was as you thought it should be that it would all be working...

Answer (score 1):

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings returns a [ConnectionStringSettingsCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You want to use ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString to get the actual connection string.

This is already a string, so you will not need the Convert.ToString() method (which is a big warning sign when used in my book, along with adding .ToString() on the end of everything).